# One to many validation

Tags: java

I have a scenario where I need to validate a list of phone numbers and make sure that each phone number, within that list, is a valid phone number (where valid phone numbers are also stored in a list).

e.g I have a list of phone numbers like this:

```
List<String> phoneNumbers = new ArrayList<String>
   (Arrays.asList("0000000001", "0000000002", "0000000003"));

List<String> validPhoneNumbers = new ArrayList<String>
   (Arrays.asList("0000000001", "0000000004", "0000000002"));
```

so I need to validate that each phone number in `phoneNumbers` list is part of `validPhoneNumbers`. If any are not in `validPhoneNumbers` then it returns `false`. Since `0000000003` is not part of the `validPhoneNumbers` list then that `phoneNumbers` list returns `false`.

---

I have the following code:

```
boolean phoneIsValid = false;
List<String> phoneNumbs = listOfPhoneNumbsValues;
if(phoneNumbs != null) {
   List<String> listOfValidMdn = listOfValidPhoneNumbsValues;
   for(String validMdn : listOfValidMdn) {
      if(phoneNumbs.equals(validMdn)) {
         //The problem I am facing is the following below on how should I 
         //store the phoneIsValid? 
         phoneIsValid = true;
         break;
      }
   }
}
```

The problem I am facing is how should I store the `phoneIsValid`? Should it be an array of boolean which then I have to iterate over at the end to see if it has any false values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should think in opposite logic: find at least one phone number that is not valid.

```
boolean atLeastOneInvalid = false;
for(String phoneNumber : phoneNumbers){
   if(!validPhoneNumbers.contains(phoneNumber)){
      atLeastOneInvalid = true;
   }
}
// here if atLeastOneInvalid is true you know that some phone number(s) is not valid
```

Comment: omg i forgot the list object has a contain function -__-. Was trying to create the logic for this over an hour now

Comment: Don't worry, you need to get the used to these data structures. Once you have, they will come to you automatically :) Btw, this code can be made faster but it is out of the question scope.

Comment: ohh gotcha, i was doing it backwards. K we can delete these comments. Sorry! I will accept your answer. Ty!

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to check ;

```
boolean allPhonesValid = validPhoneNumbers.containsAll(phoneNumbers);
```

now apply your other logic on this `boolean` param which is `allPhonesValid`.

With `Java8 StreamApi`;

```
boolean atLeastOneNumberInvalid = phoneNumbers.stream().anyMatch(phoneNumber -> !validPhoneNumbers.contains(phoneNumber));
```

**PS:** Stream solution works well instead of others performance. Because if anyMatch find first not contains , it breaks.